# How to do hapijs reverse routing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, url-routing, hapi.js

I'm searching for a reverse routing feature for Hapijs. For example, if I have the route `/route/{param1}/{param2}` named `route_name`, I want a function:

```
reverseRoute('route_name', {param1: 'value1', param2: 'value2'});
```

which returns `/route/value1/value2`

I've been googling for a while but cannot find a solution.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put together a plugin called [hapi-to](https://github.com/mtharrison/hapi-to) that can do this. It manages params, query strings, wildcards and multi-params too.

With your example, it would work like:

`request.to('route_name', { params: {param1: 'value1', param2: 'value2'} }`

Take a look at the [tests](https://github.com/mtharrison/hapi-to/blob/master/test/index.js) for some more examples of how it can be used .

Comment: Thanks! This looks exactly like what I needed. But it's annoying if I have to send params each time to view. Do you know how can I access the request object in view?

Comment: Yeah, gotcha. Unfortunately it's not something hapi-to does yet. I thought about integrated it with view helpers but didn't get anywhere yet.

Comment: Hello, I think for now I will just create the URL in route handler and pass it to the view. Although it's not elegant but it is still feasible. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the [hapi-named-routes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hapi-named-routes) plugin.

This will allow you to create routes such as:

```
{
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/about',
  config: {
    handler: function (request, reply) {
      reply.view('about');
    },
    id: 'about'
  }

}
```

so you can then reference this route in your views:

```
<a href="{{path.about}}">About</a>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I've looked at hapi-named-routes, but it's only half of what I want. It does not support generating URL from parameters.